# Problem running mvn install for geoexplorer

Tags: openlayers-2, java, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

What's the solution to this: http://www.paste.to/MjU5ODE=

I'm getting the same error on Ubuntu 12.04.
Installed with: Java 1.6.0_27 (OpenJDK), Maven 2.2.1 and Ant 1.8.2

Is the Ant version the problem since 1.8.1 is in the maven repository?

How do I resolve this? Sorry I have little experience with Maven/Ant.

Comment: Do you have the ant-contrib package installed?

Comment: Thanks for your help, ant-contrib was indeed not installed but after installing and running mvn clean install the same error remains. I will further investigate next week, any hints highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing ant-contrib really seems to be the solution to this problem. After setting up GeoExplorer from the start today I'm able to build it via mvn install. I also added some other Ant/Maven related packages, but ant-contrib looks to be the essential one that was missing. Thanks!